# Is this the correct minimal function for the given functional?

Tags: optimization, functional-equations, calculus-of-variations, euler-lagrange-equation, maxima-minima

The given functional was $\ J[f] =\int_{0}^{1} ({x^{2}-f^{2}(x) + (f'(x))^{2}})dx $. Using the Euler-Lagrange equation, I calculated that $\ L_f=-2f$, $\ L_{f'}=2f'$, and $\ \frac{d}{dx}(L_{f'})=2f'' $.

Such that $\ 0 = L_f - \frac{d}{dx}(L_{f'})= -2f-2f''$ for which the solution is:
$\ f(x)=c_2sin(x) + c_1cos(x)$

Functionals are still new to me, so any help is appreciated.

Comment: You are correct here.

Comment: Technically, in a well-posed variational problem, one needs to impose pertinent boundary conditions to consistently derive Euler-Lagrange equation. What are the boundary conditions here?

Comment: 0 and 1, as originally included, if I'm not missing something?

Comment: @Qmechanic My apologies, I now understand how my original post was lacking all the proper information. However, the problem as presented to me did not specify boundary conditions. Thanks for highlighting that.